# App.config needs dynamic value

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

My app config currently has this line  of code.

```
<add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/" />
```

However I require it having where `localhost` is the equivalent of `System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()`. Any  ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: please note that using localhost or GetHostName() or 127.0.0.1 are all as dynamic: they all refer to running computer.

Comment: Localhost is commented out in the hosts file by default.  It's a good idea to uncomment it as local dns entries can map to it and steal it causing it to not be 127.0.0.1 anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest to use `string.Format`:

```
<add baseAddressFormat = "http://{0}:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/" />
```

And then in code:

```
var baseAddress = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseAddressFormat "], System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
```

Or you can hide this `string.Format` call behind a global app configuration class property. It could be something like:

```
public class MyConfig 
{
    public string BaseAddress 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseAddressFormat "], System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This work brilliantly thank you just one side comment if someone else uses this as a reference is that some .net has "ApplicationSettings" and others have"AppSettings" but apart from that a perfect answer thank you again.

Comment: @ZoomVirus yes, you are right about `AppSettings`. I have updated the code snippets.